# Not able to read any properties from app.config file

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I am making setup file for outlook add-in.
Everything working fine but I am not able to read connection string or any key in app.config file after install add-in.

I am making setup reference from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mcsuksoldev/2010/10/01/building-and-deploying-an-outlook-2010-add-in-part-2-of-2/

What I noticed :
“Manifest” – set this to “[TARGETDIR]MyOutlookAddIn.vsto|vstolocal”.
If I use above values for Manifest that time not able to read app.config

“Manifest” – set this to “[TARGETDIR]MyOutlookAddIn.vsto”.
In this case, I am able to read app.config file but two times install add-in

Without setup, I am able to read app.config file.

My Question is.
Why I am not able to read app.config file after install add-in? What is the solution for this?

Comment: what add in did you installed?

Comment: Yes, I am able to install add-in and I have already installed add in.  I have created custom add-in for my project.